# How to show base errors on active_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the admin area, how do i go about and show the base errors (errors not specific to a field?). Ideally i would like to do this for all models.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know this too, can't find anything on it which is an issue as my delete callbacks don't show their message which is confusing for users

Comment: I just ran into this as well and would like to see an answer that would appeal to anyone wanting this in their solution.  We need a way to make this happen for all models, not have to override every form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I hope I don't get flamed for this, but I dug into the ActiveAdmin Code and found where the default form options are.

**Monkey Patch:**

```
module ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages
  class Form < Base
    private
    def default_form_config
      ActiveAdmin::PagePresenter.new do |f|
        f.semantic_errors
        f.inputs
        f.actions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That will make all the forms by default show errors that were added to base.

Comment: Is this code for displaying errors by default in all active admin forms ?

Answer (score 10):

I just found an easy way to get them.. but you still have to override the form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Blah do

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors :blah
    f.inputs do
      f.input :one
      f.input :two
    end
    f.buttons
  end  

end
```

**Update**
You can simplify it like this too:

```
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors :blah
    f.inputs
    f.buttons
  end  

end
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to show those errors also in the index-view for my model (I throw an error if an object can't be deleted).